How do I turn off auto-indent of line items in Emacs Org Mode?
In org-mode, when I try to write a list, it automatically indents the next line after I hit return.
How do I turn this off?
I read through several entries on Stack Overflow and other sources, but I could not find an answer to this concern.

Just this:
(when (fboundp 'org-indent-mode) (org-indent-mode -1))

Doesn't cause org.el to be loaded, etc. Doesn't hurt to use it in any buffer, whether or not it's in Org mode.

Use C-h m to see whether you enable the org-indent-mode minor mode. If yes, use M-x org-indent-mode to disable it in your current org buffer. If this is what you need, you can write some config like the follows to disable it whenever you are in org-mode
(use-package org
  :hook (org-mode . (lambda () (org-indent-mode -1))))


The electric-indent-mode can lead to this auto indentation.
